# Using commands in Ansible Jinja template

Tags: ansible, jinja2, ansible-template

I am trying to create a jinja2 template which will use conditioning to check the server location and then push the changes to the server accordingly.

In my template file below I tried to run command and check if it meets the expected location .

---

```
config.j2

{% if `hostname -s|cut -c 1-2` == "ny" -%}

options timeout:1 attempts:2

search us.xyz.com 

nameserver 1.1.3.2  
nameserver 1.2.3.4

{% elif `hostname -s|cut -c 1-2` == "au" -%}
options timeout:1 attempts:2
search us.xyz.com 
nameserver 1.1.3.9 

nameserver 1.2.3.8

{% endif %}
```

---

Its throwing error as :

```
"msg": "AnsibleError: template error while templating string: unexpected char u'`'
```

Does the jinja template allows using system commands or not at all ? Any suggestion or lead will be helpful !

Comment: Please edit this to use Markdown formatting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does the jinja template allows using system commands or not at all?

No, it doesn't.

Not only there is no such syntax, but templating would be executed on local machine, so `hostname` in your example would always resolve to the control machine's name.

But there is no reason to do it at all, just use Ansible in the following way:

```
{% if ansible_hostname[0:2] == "ny" -%}
```

Comment: can I use "OR" operator as ...== "ny|chg|cal" -%}  ?

Comment: Not in the way you asked.

Comment: How should It be used in the template conditioning ? Or I have to make separate elif block ?